# XCode 7 different images resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I have an iOS application supports iOS7+, i am using now Xcode 7.

I have multiple image sizes to use for iPhone 4s, 5, 6 and 6plus sizes...

I am using image assets in XCode, but i found only 3 image nodes: 1x, 2x and 3x.

[image]

How to manipulate these different sizes with these only three options in image assets?

Edit:
in the story board; i have single viewController (assumption), this viewController contains single image, how to create single image set and put all images in this set and in the run time, every device takes its suitable image size?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "image assets" section of Xcode, you can add a different image set for each distinct image that you need in your app.

To add another image set for a different type of image you just click on the plus button in the bottom left of the image assets view, and then click on "New Image Set" (see image below).

From there you can add as many image sets as you would like, with the 1x, 2x and 3x for the respective devices. The 1x size represents images that will be used for non-retina displays (everything previous to the iPhone 4). Then the 2x size is used for all phones after that except for the iPhone 6 plus and 6s plus (those two use the 3x size).

[image]

Comment: please see the edit above in the question, i need to use single image set to handle the same image view for different devices.

Comment: Got it. I am not aware of a way to do that using a single image set. Sorry that I can't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

Hope below mentioned link helps:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1